# Recreating the RenderPass every frame

Tags: vulkan

Is it an acceptable practice to recreate RenderPass(es) every frame?

In a maximally dynamic engine, a frame's composition could vary wildly from one frame to the next. One frame could require completely different RenderPasses/Subpasses from the one before.

Also, to implement something like the FrameGraph of the Frostbite engine, doesn't that necessitate (potentially) recreating the RenderPass every frame?
https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1024612/FrameGraph-Extensible-Rendering-Architecture-in

I'm not sure how expensive the creation of RenderPasses could be in different devices, like between Desktop and Mobile.

Comment: You should realize that all of your pipelines are built against a specific subpass of a specific render pass, and cannot be used in any other subpass of any other render pass (unless it's "compatible". And "compatible" is essentially defined as "created from the exact same creation info").

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out how to handle dynamic RenderPass(es), that could change dramatically each frame. Like enable/disable blurs, outlines, glows, etc. Not sure which way to go about it.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Each of those things (except maybe "outlines") looks like something that would be its own rendering operation. So you can simply choose not to rendering anything if you want it to be "off". So what's the problem? Provide an example of something that would require a change to the actual `VkRenderPass` itself

Comment: Something like a RenderPass that has a bunch of subpasses, and some of those subpasses should sometimes be done, but not other times, and the determination could only be done at runtime.

Comment: "Doing a subpass" is not some special state. If you start a subpass with `vkCmdNextSubpass`, and then immediately go to the next one, that's *fine*. It just won't do anything. So what are you asking about?

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the answer. Just go to the next subpass with vkCmdNextSubpass. For some reason, I was thinking about issues with attachments and memory possibly getting corrupted. I'm not sure why my mind was there. The answer is actually pretty simple, then. This is actually much better than I was expecting, because one can create whatever complex set for passes/subpasses, and just rebuild the cmdbuffer to leave any steps empty, and thereby skipping that part of the RenderPass without having to switch RenderPasses. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat unanswerable as stated. How to architecture your engine and which compromises you take is bit opinion-based. And every function (that is not a no op) is technically less expensive if called outside render loop, than every time inside inside render loop. It is just a matter of whether it is viable to call these outside every frame from functional and architectural concerns of your codebase.

Simply treat `vkCreateRenderPass` and `vkCreateFramebuffer` as potentially expensive operations. Those functions are two opportunites for the driver to form an optimization strategy (which can be relatively expensive). So keep them outside a hotspot, if you can. Additionally, it is possible to cache them, even when created inside a frame.

It should be somewhat less expensive for contemporary desktop GPUs, and somewhat more expensive on mobile (resp. tiler) GPUs. But that is subject to change across GPU generations, and perhaps even across driver versions.

Comment: My issue was mostly about not understanding how to handle dynamic scene composition, where renderpasses/subpasses where not always the same. After considering Nicol Bolas comments, I realized that I can accomplish this by: 1) Omitting the vkCmds* that correspond to the passes, which essentially turns them off while keeping the RenderPass the same. 2) Use different RenderPass objects if the order of the passes change. I was concerned with how I would go about reordering passes, until I realized that I don't really need to take that approach, because that wont be a common occurrence.